# Test overwriting console.log with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm filtering some messages with the following code:

```
const consoleLog = console.log;
console.log = (...args) => {
  if (args.length === 0 || typeof args[0] !== 'string' || !args[0].includes('[HMR]')) {
    consoleLog.apply(console, args);
  }
};
```

How can I test the console output of this function? Normally, I'd just mock `console.log`, but in this case it's overwritten by the code above, so I can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally not a good practice to monkey-patch global APIs. And it's better to expose original function just in case, at least for testing purposes.

It would be easier to test it if it were more flexible, e.g. patched code could be controlled with environment variables, in case there's a need to fall back to original behaviour:

```
console._logOriginal = console.log;
console.log = (...args) => {
  if (
    !process.env.NO_HMR_SPAM ||
    (args.length === 0 || typeof args[0] !== 'string' || !args[0].includes('[HMR]'))
  ) {
    console._logOriginal(...args);
  }
};
```

In this case `console._logOriginal` can be spied.

Otherwise original `console.log` should be backed up before this module is evaluated, it shouldn't be imported before that:

```
const consoleLogOriginal = console.log;

it('...', async () => {
  const consoleLogSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
  await import('moduleThatManglesConsole');
  console.log('[HMR]');
  expect(consoleLogSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  console.log('');
  expect(consoleLogSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('');
})

afterEach(() => {
  console.log = consoleLogOriginal;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or don't mess with the original `console.log` at all.

```
const consoleLog = (...args) => {
  if (args.length === 0 || typeof args[0] !== 'string' || !args[0].includes('[HMR]')) {
    console.log.apply(console, args);
  }
};
```

Then utilize `consoleLog` exclusively in your application code.

Benefit of this indirection:

- It's safer. You never monkey-patch the original `console.log` at all.
- It's more future-proof. If you switch from `console.log` to e.g. a 3rd-party logging framework later, you don't have to adjust all your logging code.

However, if you are intentionally configuring code beyond your control (3rd-party) that uses `console.log`, this of course will not work for that case.

With this approach, for unit testing, spy on `console.log` (which was never modified) as recommended in the answer from estus.